# Checking if an array has all unique elements

Tags: purescript

Do any of the core purescript libraries come with a predicate that evaluates whether an array (or foldable) has unique elements?

I've searched a bit and found `nub` and Data.Set's `fromFoldable` which will return data with only unique elements.

Right now, I'm just comparing the length of a `nub`'ed array with the original, though that's a quick and dirty way to do it as I don't need the intermediate result.

```purs
allUnique :: forall a. Ord a => Array a -> Boolean
allUnique xs = length xs == (length $ nub xs)
```

Figured I'd ask if this (or something close) already exists before re-creating the wheel (so to speak).

Comment: I think this is fine. `nub` is N*log(N), so the `length` calls would be swallowed in that.

Comment: On large sets of data, allUnique could return after seeing 2 elements (if they're the same). Still N*log(N), I suppose

Comment: If you know that your data is always shaped such that duplicates are more likely to appear at the front - then for sure, you can implement a lazy-ish check like that, and I can show you how. But if you don't know that about your data, then this is just a premature optimization, which is the root of we all know what.